# Why after used Floating action button apps got crushed ? Android studio XML

Tags: android, floating-action-button

my textview is ok, my button is ok, but when i'm adding Floatingaction button then, after run automatically apps closed & Crushed. Why ?

Here's my XML code & I've not put anything in MainActivity.kt file. Anyone please help me.

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/primary_color"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/button" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/secondary_color"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:contentDescription="@string/email_icon"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</LinearLayout>```


I should show the Button, but not showing this.
````

Comment: please share crash log

Comment: Here's the crush log: 
https://ibb.co/tm6qRYr 
Screenshot here. I can't send whole log text because, showing too long text here.

Comment: please read your crash log as it states that the style on your component requires your app theme. The theme of your floating button is not as per your app.